# trying store token in shared preferences but not working

Tags: api, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, token

in flutter project i'm trying to store token and user id in shared preferences but it does not work!token is string and user id is integer can anyone help?

```
final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['login_token'] != null) {
        _token = responseData['login_token'];
        _userID = int.parse(responseData['account_id']);
      }
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final userData = json.encode({'userId': _userID, 'token': _token});
      prefs.setString('userData', userData);

      final extractData =
          json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      if (extractData['userId']) {
        _userID = int.parse(extractData['userId']);
        print("id2" + _userID.toString());
        _token = extractData['token'];
        print('token is:' + _token);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin saves data asynchronously. So you should add `await` before `prefs.setString()` to your example if you want to immedietly get saved value:

```
      await prefs.setString('userData', userData);
      final extractData =
          json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

By the way, consider to use [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to store sensitive data like access tokens. I'm not sure if your token is secret or not, just think  about it.